# Strings are not getting concatenated properly

Tags: c#

i have below code where string dont get concatenated

```
string postCode = "1245";
string city = "Stockholm";
string postCodeAndCity = postCode ?? " " + " " + city ?? " ";
```

I get output as **1245**. Not sure why it excludes city.

But this line works

```
string.Concat(postCode??" ", " ", city?? " ");
```

so why the first approach dont work?

Comment: Add parenthesis to delimit your phrases: `(postCode ?? " ") + " " + (city ?? " ")`

Comment: why not just use `postCode + " " + city`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere If `postCode` was null, then you'd get one space before the city, instead of two. `postCode + " " + city` is equivalent to `(postCode ?? "") + " " + (city ?? "")`

Comment: Ok, so let´s ask OP, if we really wants **two** spaces, when `postCode` is `null`.

Comment: I suspect what the OP *might* want is something like `string.Join(" ", new[] { postCode, city }.Where(x => x != null))` -- i.e. if they're both not null, use both with a space between them. If either one is null, use the other. If both are null, take an empty string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `??` operator associates like this:

```
string postCodeAndCity = postCode ?? (" " + " " + city ?? (" "));
```

So if `postCode` is not null, it just takes `postCode`. If `postCode` is null, then it takes `(" " + " " + city ?? (" "))`.

You can see this from the [precedence table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/), where `??` has lower precedence than `+`. Therefore `+` binds more tightly than `??`, i.e. `a ?? b + c` binds as `a ?? (b + c)`, not as `(a ?? b) + c`.

However, in:

```
string.Concat(postCode??" ", " ", city?? " ");
```

The commas of course have higher precedence than the `??`. The equivalent using `+` would be:

```
(postCode ?? " ") + " " + (city ?? " ");
```

---

I suspect what you might want to do is:

1. If both `postCode` and `city` are not null, take both with a space between them.
2. If one is null but the other isn't, take the non-null one.
3. If both are null, take an empty string.

You can write this long-hand:

```
if (postCode != null)
{
    if (city != null)
        return postCode + " " + city;
    else
        return city;
}
else
{
    if (postCode != null)
        return postCode;
    else
        return "";
}
```

You can write this a bit shorter (although slightly more expensively) with:

```
string.Join(" ", new[] { postCode, city }.Where(x => x != null));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use string interpolation for this:

```
var output = $"{postCode} {city}"
```

For more information see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: Note that this does something different to the code that the OP posted.

Comment: you mean the missing blanks after postCode and city if it's empty? So if postCode and city is empty the string contains 3 spaces? hmmmmm i doubt he wants to have 3 spaces

Comment: Sure, but if you give code which does something different to what the question asked for (even if you think that the question is wrong), it's worth pointing that out in your answer. Also note that string interpolation is significantly more expensive than string concatenation, so I think "you should use string interpolation for this" is a bit strong.

Comment: (although in this case, the compiler spots that the string interpolation can be converted to concatenation, and does this for you)

Comment: jeha you are right. i should have been using "could" instead of "should" but i wont agree with the "significant more expensive" part. You should explain that the "more expensive" part is just a problem if you run this in a loop like a million times. So without having a context i guess the statement is not correct

Comment: anyway. he have got multiple solutions and an idea of what is possible.

Comment: Note that string interpolation *is* more expensive than string concatenation - that's why there's a lot of logic in the compiler to turn interpolation into concatenation where that's possible. Whether that expense matters is a different matter, and that depends on context. But there are times where concatenation is more appropriate than interpolation, which is why I think "should" is a bit strong.

Comment: i prefer clean and readable code...
1. to understand you long-hand code you need to check each line with an example in your head.
2. ```$"{postCode} {city}".trim()``` produces the same empty string... he can decide what kind of output he likes.
3. i guess the ```string.Join(" ", new[] { postCode, city }.Where(x => x != null));``` is the slowest solution you could choose....

Comment: There's an important distinction between "these are the options, these are the trade-offs, use the one that's most suitable to your situation" and "you should always use this option". I'm simply arguing that dogmatically going "always use interpolation, never use concatenation" is wrong, because there are *some* non-zero number of cases where concatenation is the objectively better tool. I said above that whether the expense of a more readable option matters in practice depends on context.